# Limit of a nearly Riemann sum

Tags: riemann-integration

On of my student asked me to find $$\lim_{n\to+\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt{(n+k)(n+k+1)}}$$

I tried to write it as a Riemann sum, but the term $ \frac 1n $ disturbs.

I tried to use the fact that
$$n+k\le n+k+1 \le 2n+1$$
but no way.
Thank you in advance.
appreciate.

Comment: $$\frac1{n+k+1}\le\frac{1}{\sqrt{(n+k)(n+k+1)}}\le\frac1{n+k}$$

Comment: @ProfessorVector Yes, thanks a lot for the idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{n+k+1} \leq\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt{(n+k)(n+k+1)}}\leq\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{n+k} $$

Let, $S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{n+k}$

And $T_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt{(n+k)(n+k+1)}}$

Then we have,

$$S_n- \frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{2n+1}\leq T_n\leq S_n$$

Now use sandwich theorem.

Comment: we use $\int_0^1\frac{1}{1+x}dx$.